# My site is vulnerable for sql injections, right?

Tags: sql, security, sql-injection

On one of my customers sites I think I've found a big security issue.
I found out that when I entered an semicolon ' in the search box, the script threw an sql error. So I started playing...

Entering the SQL command below in the searchbox executes the query:
`'+AND+product_description.description+LIKE+'%Computers%`

The query is executed on the database!

Is it safe to say that a hacker can do harm with executing selects, inserts and delete queries too? Based on the fact that my query is executed I'm almost sure it should be possible to do harm... Am I right?

Comment: Might be a bit of a stretch to call it "your database" from now on ...

Comment: @Eugen: This is one of the best comments I've read on SO :D

Comment: @Eugen: I actually laughed-out-loud :)

Comment: I didn't, as this is a serious question. And the answer didn't help me at all. I think a more appropriate place for posting jokes is at http://www.jokesforum.com/

Comment: @quokka: The answers didn't help you? Why not? They answer your question perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right. You should always sanitize the input and not use it directly in such a way, or it's sooner or later will be compromised by SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. This code is open for sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

That definitely is a form of SQL injection, and you're correct in being worried.

However, that alone is not enough to tell whether or not you can do things other than alter the query parameters in unexpected ways. The query might for example be altered to retrieve data from tables not listed in the original query, which might well be bad enough.

I strongly recommend to avoid using string concatenation in building SQL queries, but instead using "prepared statements" which only allow to replace provided placeholders with the user-selected data values. Even there the application would be wise to check the values for at least some sanity before passing them on to the database-

Answer (score 0):

Your site is open to SQL injection attacks, and there is a lot you can do to protect it, but first short term thing I would recommend is create a user-id with only read-rights and use this ID for all queries.   Hackers will still be able to extract data from your database, but won't be as easy to update or delete rows or tables...

Comment: Hi, want to thank everybody for helping out. We're currently looking for a developer to hire and I don't want to mess with this app code myself. Till we found a programmer, will this htacces solution be first line of defense? Look good as temporary solution to me, or am I wrong? http://nzflew.blogspot.com/2010/03/htaccess-file-to-help-prevent-sql.html

Comment: What is the APP written in?   If a Microsoft technology, this is a good chance the connection information is stored in a configuration file, so you can update that to use a read-only connection without touching the code...   Look for web.config or even global.asa.   If you know what the site is written in, people here will likely chime in to help you find the connection info

Comment: Hi Sparky, it's written in PHP, but I can't create read only user as it's a e-commerce app that extensively writes to database. That's why I'm looking for a solution like htaccess untill an experienced programmer can look at the code in detail. The htaccess solution I mentioned seems ok to me as temporary first line of defense. Seems to block all harmful requests. l Or am I missing something? Any thoughts on this are welcome and highly appreciated!

Comment: Blacklists are very problematic in their own right, as you will never catch all attack vectors - it's just not a practical problem to solve. But your main problem with this, is it doesn't care what is in data posted in forms - such as search boxes.

Comment: I agree with Cheekysoft, Blacklists give a false sense of security, they are very unlikely to catch everything.   The code in the htaccess would help, but recognize it is only a stop gap measure, sort of a picket fence being put up when you really need a moat and drawbridge.